# React Native USB connection and file transfer

Tags: android, react-native

I m building an app that will need to connect to a mini pc and transfer files from my phone to that PC. How can I make the connection between the phone and the PC?

Comment: Mostly we use a USB cable. And one does not need an app for it to transfer files fom Android device to PC.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
Just u need to enable USB Debugging in your physical device
and everything you found on the link .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tyler2P. That does not matter. Nobody cares. We are here to help OP. That is good enough. If you think its not then please add the essential parts. We have no time for it.